# Can I use some vector drawing to replace a png in my html?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html5-animation

I have a very well optimized web site and I would like to optimize even more. Specifically I have a fairly large logo that's currently a png. The logo is a very simple shape.

I've never seen this done before but is there a way that I could code in the drawing of this logo using some vector drawing code within my html? I realize it's probably possible with HTML5 but what about HTML4 and current browser support.

Thanks,

Jane Easterby

Comment: I think it may be even possible with `CSS`

Comment: take a look at http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2010/11/27/flag-of-pakistan-with-pure-css/

Answer (score 1):

Using SVG within your website will only have compatibility with some non-IE browsers.
SVG though could be replaced dynamically by your script based on the visitor though.

And yes, it can be done in HTML 4 (by some browsers, generally those that already support HTML 5 anyway.)

Some guides:

http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp

http://codinginparadise.org/projects/svgweb/docs/QuickStart.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589526(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. How about the new IE9? Does that allow SVG?

Comment: Im pretty sure it does. And it also has HTML5. IE9 features and cool info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff468705

Comment: I notice that you are new to StackOverflow. When you are happy and feel that your question is answered, please click the Tick next to the answer you feel answered your question the most. :) I hope your project goes well.